# Is it possible to autocall at a specified date and time?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know whether is it possible to make an autocall to a predefined number, at a predefined date and time in iOS using some system API, or in some another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try only do this only UILocalNotification alert below link for download my example 
project

http://www.4shared.com/zip/QVgHkM1n/Notification.html

**Note: call function is worked only iphone real device..!**

Thanks..!

Comment: ok. the call will go to the particular number on that time itself?

Comment: you can mention the number dynamically to set notification title phone  number and read  notification title application did receive notification in you project delegate class method change call nsurl to set phone number from notification title..!

Answer (score 0):

this wil help u [Repeating an iOS local notification](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html)